# How can one recursively rename directories without sed or rename?

Tags: bash, find, rename, recursive

I am trying to rename a few directories that contain "Fever" to contain "Malaria" instead. The instruction is to do it without sed or rename. So far, my errors include mostly lines like `mv: cannot stat ‘retest\nretest/Section-01\nretest/Section-02\nretest/Section-03\nretest/Section-04’: No such file or directory`.

The best my code have done is rename directories in the first level.

Here's my directory structure:

`Fever-A/Malaria-A-A`

`Fever-B/Fever-B-A`

`Fever-B/Fever-B-B`

`Fever-C/Malaria-A`

`Fever-C/Fever-C-A`

`Fever-C/Fever-C-B`

`Fever-C/Fever-C-C-C`

`Fever-D/Malaria-A`

`Fever-D/Malaria-B`

The code I have so far is :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Access directory
#cd $1

# Find all subdirectories in $1 and load up array
all=($(find $1 -type d))
#echo ${all[@]}

# Loop through directories above
for dir in ${all[@]}
do
    # echo "$dir"
    cd $dir
    # List files with "Section" in name
    subdir=(:"Section*")

    # A second loop for directories in each dir with "Section*"
    for item in ${subdir[@]}
    do
            echo $item
            echo "--------------------"

            # Rename operation
            mv $item ${item//Fever/Malaria}
    done
    cd $1
done
```

Another approach I've considered is using a function like so, but it's not working either:

```
#!/bin/bash

rename(){
    old_names=($(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type d))

    for item in ${old_names[@]}
    do
            if [[ $item = *Section* ]]; then
                    new_name=${item//Fever/Malaria}
                    mv $item $new_name
            elif [[ $1 != $item ]]; then
                    rename $item
            fi

            rename $1
    done
}

rename $1
```

Comment: There are several questions on this subject if you search `rename` tag... There are answers that show how to do this properly (that is, using `find` with `-exec` and `-depth`) and some of them use just parameter expansion (no `sed`, no `perl rename`).

Comment: What should the _resulting_ directory structure look like?  Please edit the question with these results.

Comment: "The instruction is" -- is this homework? :) Or is there some other reason to specifically not use `sed`?

Comment: @ilkkachu Tools like sed and rename make things easy true, but I'm wondering what really happens under the hood. The _resulting_ directory structure remains the same.

Comment: Under the hood, a bunch of `getdents(2)` (or `readdir(3)`) calls are made to list the files during a recursive walk of the tree, and the files  are then moved with calls to `rename(2)`... You could implement the recursive logic with shell functions, but to get a bit closer to the OS interface, you'd better write a C program.

Answer (score 1):

As Don Crissti mentions, there are a lot of ways of solving this with `find`.  But I thought, since we're only talking two directory levels, that we can do this slightly differently with only one external command: `mv`

```
#!/bin/bash

fixdir()
{
  local f g

  for f in Fever*
  do
    if [ -e "$f" ]
    then
      g=Malaria"${f#Fever}"
      if [ -e "$g" ]
      then
        echo "Skipping $1/$f->$1/$g; already exists"
      else
        # echo "Renaming $1/$f->$1/$g"
        mv "$f" "$g"
      fi
    fi
  done
}

for a in *
do
  if [ -d "$a" ]
  then
    (cd $a ; fixdir $a )
  fi
done

fixdir .
```

The results:

```
$ ls -1d F*/*
Fever-A/Malaria-A-A
Fever-B/Fever-B-A
Fever-B/Fever-B-B
Fever-C/Fever-C-A
Fever-C/Fever-C-B
Fever-C/Fever-C-C-C
Fever-C/Malaria-A
Fever-D/Malaria-A
Fever-D/Malaria-B

$ ./fix

$ ls -1d M*/*
Malaria-A/Malaria-A-A
Malaria-B/Malaria-B-A
Malaria-B/Malaria-B-B
Malaria-C/Malaria-A
Malaria-C/Malaria-C-A
Malaria-C/Malaria-C-B
Malaria-C/Malaria-C-C-C
Malaria-D/Malaria-A
Malaria-D/Malaria-B
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for dir in $(find /startdir -depth -type d -name '*Fever*')
do   dn=$(basename $dir)
     mv $dir $(dirname $dir)/${dn//Fever/Malaria}
done
```

That should do it. (Change startdir to your start directory)

The find will only return directories containing 'Fever'.
the mv command uses bash inline substitution to return a string with Fever changed to Malaria.

The added -depth makes it process subdirs first.

Comment: What happens to `/startdir/Fever-A/Fever-A` ?  That'll result in `mv /startdir/Fever-A/Fever-A /startdir/Malaria-A/Malaria-A` but that directory doesn't exist...  or if 'Fever-A' gets renamed first then the `find` will then start looking for a directory that doesn't exist and won't find the new `Malaria-A/Fever-A`.

Comment: Good catch! Added a -depth to process subdirs first, and some more cruft to rename only the end directory segment.

Comment: Good update.  Now the next problem; what if there's a directory called `Fever A-B` - ie has a space in it?   (I'm not picking on you; this is a good learning opportunity - there's a _lot_ of hidden gotchas in something so simple!  Let me know if you don't want to do this here and I'll stop)